# NodeJS execute issue

Tags: node.js

'node -v' have different results on same "Amazon Linux 2" machine. this impact my ci/cd process, why this happen?

1. first linux account result 'v12.22.12'
2. second linux account result:

node: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by node)

node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)

Comment: i resolved this by add command before build. 
```export PATH=/usr/local/n/versions/node/12.19.0/bin:$PATH```.
now i'm using docker with gitlab Kubernetes executor, will never meet such issue again.

Answer (score 4):

Ok so I have an Elastic Beanstalk application and ran into same issue when trying to install node vis nvm install node.

The solution is to specify node version 16.x in package.json

```
{
  "engines": {
    "node": "= 16.x"
  },
}
```

I did using node version 18.x. I tried upgrading the glibc via yum and tar but just ran into more issues.

(UPDATE)
In order to avoid installing version 18 automatically use these commands to grab lts version.

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
  . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
nvm install --lts
nvm use --lts
node -e "console.log('Running Node.js ' + process.version)"
npm install yarn
```

If you already ran nvm install then you have to remove v18 before you install lts.

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
      . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
nvm uninstall v18.0.0
nvm install --lts
nvm use --lts
node -e "console.log('Running Node.js ' + process.version)"
npm install yarn
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue. Am running a ruby app 3.0 in elastic beanstalk.
A quick respite for me and anyone else in my position was to downgrade the platform version and save some unpleasant client calls for offline apps:)